# load jsp page from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have 3-4 jsp pages, and iam calling them in each other.I could have kept all the code in one page but then it was getting to complex to handle,so broke the page in 3-4 different pages.And iam successfully able call them one after the other.But the problem is when i call these two pages the page just overlap and the length of the page increases.

```
<other code above this>
<%@ include file="northern_content.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="southern_content.jsp" %> 
<No code after these files are included>
```

I want that if i click a particular option then either one of them (according to the choice of click) should be loaded.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: JSP content will not load, or function in a HTML page. You'll need to redirect to the page as max noted.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple

```
<a href="northern_content.jsp">Northern Content</a>
```

This way, you click on a page, you will be taken to that page. is this what you are looking for?

Or you can write this on a button click or any other event handling, if you have a form

```
onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'northern_content.jsp'
```

Here you use javascript to change the action of the form

Comment: this i will to reload the entire page right.. but i want it happen in place.. hope your getting what trying to say

Comment: ok, use Ajax on button click, get the content, and show it in a <div>. And hide any other div that you do not want to display.

Comment: i have no exp in ajax can u give an example on how can i do it.

Comment: infact loading a page using ajax is not a good way. If you wantto replace some content, you can load it using ajax and replace the content.